# Tool for phonetic transcriptions of a specific list of words

Tags: ipa

Looking for a tool that will accept a file with a list of Basic English words as input and give the phonetic spellings/ transcriptions of the words in IPA as output.

If that's not available, any resource where I could get phonetic spellings of many words as a list will also do

TIA :)

Comment: Do you have a specific language in mind? For coverage of many languages at once, you can try wiktionary and look up your words there.

Comment: For English, [Kenyon and Knott](https://archive.org/details/pronouncingdicti00unse/page/n5/mode/2up?view=theater) is available online free. You could program it easily; it's not just a scan.

Comment: It takes maybe 5 minutes to decode the transcription system of this: http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/cgi-bin/cmudict

Comment: I was able to do it with no code on this desktop app - http://www.photransedit.com/